# enforce-guard fails in Zelcore and XWallet

Tags: pact, pact-lang

Whenever I call a function that has `(enforce-guard some-guard)` from X-wallet or Zelcore it always fails with the error `Keyset failure (keys-all)`

I have no issues when doing this from Chainweaver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to fix this**

This is an issue if you are also providing capabilities with your request.

To fix this, you will need to put `enforce-guard` within a capability too.
So you will need to do something like

```
(defcap VERIFY_GUARD (some-guard:guard)
    (enforce-guard some-guard)
)
```

And wherever you would call `enforce-guard` , you will then need to do

```
(with-capability (VERIFY_GAURD some-guard) 
   ; Guarded code here
)
```

**Why does this happen?**

Chainweaver allows you to select unrestricted signing keys, which provides a key/guard for `enforce-guard` to work with.

However X-Wallet and Zelcore don't provide this if capabilities present on the request (otherwise they do).

It is probably better practice to add `enforce-guard` into capabilities anyways and use `require-capability` in places where you expect the guard to pass.